# Как записать данные в dataGridView с phpmyadmin

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть своя бд, которой я управляю в phpmyadmin. Данные я туда записываю в таком виде(см. код). Как мне подключить бд к моему dataGridView? Чтобы после нажатие клавиши вся моя бд переносилась в dataGridView.

```
  private void insertData()
    {
        string conStr = "server=127.0.0.1;user=user;" +
                         "database=newBase;password=12345";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            try
            {
                string a = File.ReadAllText(@"title.txt", Encoding.Default);
                string b = File.ReadAllText(@"text_out.txt", Encoding.Default);


                string sql = "INSERT INTO items (Name, Cost) VALUES (@a, @b)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки данных в DataGridView я предпочитаю использовать DataTable. 
`datagridview1.DataSource = GetComments();`

Примерный метод выгрузки из БД:

```
    private DataTable GetComments()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mysqlCSB;
        mysqlCSB = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        mysqlCSB.Server = "127.0.0.1";
        mysqlCSB.Database = "mytest";
        mysqlCSB.UserID = "root";
        mysqlCSB.Password = "123";
        string queryString = @"SQL запрос";
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = mysqlCSB.ConnectionString;
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(queryString, con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        dt.Load(dr);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Обрабатываем ошибку
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```